# Проблема импортирования модулей Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Имеется папка modules, а в ней 2 файла: `fibo.py` и `main.py`.

В файле `main.py` я пытаюсь импортировать функции из файла `fibo.py` и ввожу `import fibo.py`. К сожалению интерпретатор не находит модуль.

Поискал решение в интернете и писали что нужно ввести `from . import` Так модуль виден в автодополнении, 
но все равно пишет: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Через интерактивный интерпретатор такой проблемы нету, только в vscode.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html -- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp -- https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо просто написать `import fibo`, а не `import fibo.py`, либо `from fibo import имяфункции`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import fibo.py
```

Замените на (если это `__main__` пакет):

```py
import fibo
# или
from fibo import функция...
```

Или добавьте файл `__init__.py` в директорию `modules/` и потом импортируйте (если пакет не `__main__`):

```py
from . import fibo
# или
from .fibo import функция...
```

Comment: Пробовал по разному, к сожалению все равно выдает ошибку ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent packag попробую поискать решения в анлоязычных источниках, возможно дело в настройках vscode

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил строчки

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('путь до папки')
```

Затем импортировал нужный модуль и все заработало. Выглядит конечно не особо, но вроде бы работает